# Configure List of Beans with different configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

I have a Spring Boot data-cleaning app that we use for many different companies. I've built a library of cleaning modules that our team can configure as needed for a particular client. I'm looking to extend what I've built and I just can't get it to work.

Summarizing the problem, I think I'm trying to have a List of beans that are each configured differently where there may be multiple instances of the same class.

Here's a sample of the desired configuration (using application.yml):

```
app.dataEnrichmentSteps:
  - name: Module1 #used to derive name of the Class that has the functionality
    filters:
      - name: FieldIsNotBlank #used to derive name of "filter" classname
        field: someRecordFieldName
      - name: FieldIsBlank
        field: someOtherRecordFieldName
    config:
      mod1cfg-a: someVal
      mod1cfg-b: someVal
  - name: Module2
    filters:
      - name: FieldIsNotBlank #used to derive name of "filter" classname
        field: someRecordFieldName
    config:
      mod2cfg-a: someVal
      mod2cfg-b: someVal
  - name: Module1 #this instance of Module1 has different config, and needs to run after the previous 2
    config:
      mod1cfg-a: someOtherVal
      mod2cfg-b: someOtherValAgain
  - name: Module3
    config:
      mod3cfg-a: hopefully you get the point
```

The app needs to be flexible enough to allow any module, in any order, any number of times.  Currently, on app startup, I have a `@Bean` that pulls in the steps and builds the instances of the Services (based on the Name) and passes in the config. Here's the Configuration class that Spring populates for me (which I don't like, but is all I could get to work):

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app")
public class ModuleConfig {
    private List<EnrichmentConfig> dataEnrichmentSteps;

    @Data
    public static class EnrichmentConfig{
        //what kind of Enrichment are we doing?
        private String name;

        //how is the enrichment service configured?
        private HashMap<String, String> config; 

        //on which fields should the enrichment execute on?
        private List<HashMap<String,String>> filters; 
    }
}
```

I'm struggling with the dynamic nature of this configuration. Ideally, I'd absolutely love it if each module could define a POJO for its configuration instead of me working with Maps, but everything I come across suggests a fixed configuration structure instead of what I think needs to be flexible.

I am familiar with `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` when working with Jackson and having a JSON payload that might have a bit of dynamically structured JSON, though I can't seem to figure out how to do something similar for Spring Configuration.

Comment: there's probably a good question here, but I've read this 3 times and can't figure it out yet :( is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've revised the question, hopefully simplifying the scenario.

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but it seems like you are trying to do some sort of `@ConditionalOnClass`, but slightly more involved.

Comment: I'm trying to make a "pipeline" of steps that are completely configuration driven. I have 5 different modules that are pretty generic that can be reused multiple times in the same pipeline.

Comment: What this enables me to do is build a List<Enrichment> (where Enrichment is an Interface) that has 1..N different objects that are called sequentially. The list can be composed of instances of different classes, or multiple instances of the same class. What matters, is that each object will have different configuration.

Comment: right, so in essence, you are trying to create some `List<Enrichment>` that is completely driven from your `yaml` file. and your pain comes from the fact that this is using a `Map` for those properties. Ideally this should directly map to a `POJO` of some kind, right?

Comment: Yes, at least I think so!  The configuration attributes being different for each class implementing Enrichment means I can't have a single nice clean POJO that Spring can populate. I'm left with a Map<String, String> which works for flat configuration (such as EnrichmentConfig.config) but not for anything more hierarchical (such as EnrichmentConfig itself, or EnrichmentConfig.filters).

Comment: yeah, it's almost like you need some sort of parser here, that can understand what those `filters` are supposed to look like, for example. I mean even the implementation with `List<Map<String, String>>` is probably crazy because of (potentially?) many types of filters like `FieldIsNotBlank`... I think I understand your domain problem (and it is interesting). I know that you can [try a custom conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-conversion), but I have never tried it on my own

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Configuration for a List of differently configured items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176158/spring-configuration-for-a-list-of-differently-configured-items)

Comment: @AdamErstelle What did you end up doing eventually?
I think I have a use case similar to yours but the structure of my properties is static, just the value will differ. For the set of properties with different values, I need to create different beans. Any suggestion would be appreciated?