# Spring Configuration for a List of differently configured items

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm looking to use Spring configuration to dynamically configure a list of different objects (shapes).  The list can vary greatly by each deployment of the app, sometimes having 1 shape in total, sometimes many variations of the same shape among other shapes.

One example of the intended configuration would look something like this:

```
app.shapes:
  - type: Circle
    radius: 3
    colors:
      - fill: red
        border: green
  - type: Rectangle
    length: 4
    width: 2
  - type: Circle
    radius: 5
    colors:
     - fill: blue
       border: black
  - type: Triangle
    base: 5
    height: 2
```

and the code I have to date looks like this:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigListShapesApplication {

    @Autowired
    private ShapesConfig shapesConfig;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigListShapesApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void logResults() {
        log.debug("We have {} shapes configured", shapesConfig.getShapes().size());
        for(Shape shape : shapesConfig.getShapes()) {
            log.debug("Shape is of type {} and class is instance of {}", 
                    shape.getType(), shape.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }

    @Data
    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app")
    public class ShapesConfig {
        private List<Shape> shapes;
    }

    @Data
    public class Shape {
        private String type;
    }

    @Data
    public class Circle extends Shape {
        private Integer radius;
        private Colors colors;
    }

    @Data
    public class Rectangle extends Shape {
        private Integer length;
        private Integer width;
        private Colors colors;
    }

    @Data
    public class Triangle extends Shape {
        private Integer base;
        private Integer height;
    }

    @Data
    public class Colors {
        private String fill;
        private String border;
    }
}
```

Each shape can have its own configuration structured however makes the most sense for it.

With the code I have now, when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target [Bindable@3b152928 type = java.util.List<com.example.configlistshapes.ConfigListShapesApplication$Shape>, value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[[empty]]] failed:

    Property: app.shapes[0].colors[0].border
    Value: green
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml] - 6:17
    Reason: The elements [app.shapes[0].colors[0].border, ....repeat lots...] were left unbound.
    Property: app.shapes[0].colors[0].fill
    Value: red
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml] - 5:15
    Reason: The elements [app.shapes[0].colors[0].border ....repeat lots...] were left unbound.
    Property: app.shapes[0].radius
    Value: 3
.... many more
```

I have looked at the [Spring Properties Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-conversion) docs, but it looks like guidance for converting a single property. I think I'm looking at some sort of conversion to take a block of configuration (each Shape), then creating the correct object based on the type.

I am familiar with `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` when working with Jackson and having a JSON payload that might have a bit of dynamically structured JSON, though I can't seem to figure out how to do something similar for Spring Configuration.

If it helps, I've created a [GitHub project](https://github.com/adamerstelle/spring-config-list-shapes) that can be pulled down to easily run this [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm aware this is the same root problem I'm trying to solve in a Question I asked earlier, unsure if I should have edited the previous question (premise and content are vastly different) or if I should just plain old delete the previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66165605/configure-list-of-beans-with-different-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Spring has no way to know which specific class to instantiate, it will just assume you want an instance of `Shape`.

The error you got is simply due to the fact that you forgot to declare the `Shape` class as `static`.

If you really mean to retain the polymorphic nature of your configuration, you'd have to do something like this:

0. Remember to make all nested configuration classes `static`
1. Add a `ShapeFactory`, able to determine which kind of shape should be instantiated depending on the type, eg.:

```java
    @Data
    public static class ShapeFactory {
        private String type;
        private Integer radius;
        private Colors colors;
        private Integer length;
        private Integer width;
        private Integer base;
        private Integer height;

        public Shape draw() {
            if (type.equals("Circle")) {
                return new Circle(radius, colors, type);
            } else if(type.equals("Rectangle") {
                ...
            } ...
            
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Shape type " + type);
        }
    }
```

2. Add the missing constructors in the configuration classes. If you want the `ShapeFactory.draw` method to build objects with one-liners, you will have to add specifically tailored constructors to do so. Otherwise, you can build the object with the default constructor and set the properties one by one. Eg. of the former:

```java
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Shape {
        private String type;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Circle extends Shape {
        private Integer radius;
        private Colors colors;

        public Circle(Integer radius, Colors colors, String type) {
            super(type);
            setRadius(radius);
            setColors(colors);
        }
    }
```

3. Edit the main configuration `ShapesConfig` class as follows:

```java
    @Data
    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
    public class ShapesConfig {
        private List<ShapeFactory> shapes;
        private List<Shape> actualShapes;

        @PostConstruct
        public void setUp() {
            setActualShapes(shapes.stream().map(ShapeFactory::draw).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
    }
```

All the shapes can now be retrieved via `shapesConfig.getActualShapes()`.

Comment: So this solution requires the ShapeFactory to know all the combinations of configuration properties ahead of time.  In my real-world scenario, there are dozens and dozens of configuration properties and it would not be clean to have the ShapeFactory know about all of them.

Comment: Don't think there's any other way if you need to retain the polymorphic nature of your configuration. You'd otherwise have to resort to Map-typed properties, which is more of a headache to handle in my opinion.